# Removing border from TextArea in CodenameOne causes the component to stop growing to fit text

Tags: codenameone

I want to implement a TextArea in CodenameOne as follows:

```
private Container getMessageContainer(String message) {
    Container con = new Container(new BorderLayout());

    TextArea ta = new TextArea();
    ta.setGrowByContent(true);
    ta.setSingleLineTextArea(false);
    ta.setScrollVisible(true);
    ta.setUIID("DialogTextArea");
    ta.setEditable(false);
    ta.setFocusable(false);
    ta.setText(message);

    con.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, ta);

    return con;
}
```

I then have a Theme Component in the theme.res file called `DialogTextArea` deriving `TextArea`, as follows:
[image: DialogTextAreaTheme]

This TextArea is then put on a Dialog as follows:

```
    public MessageDialog(NotificationType notificationType, String title, String message,
        boolean fallback) {
    this.notificationType = notificationType;
    this.fallback = fallback;
    this.buildTitle(title);
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    this.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, getContentConainer(message));
    this.addComponent(BorderLayout.SOUTH, getButtonContainer());
}

private Container getContentConainer(String message) {
    Container con = new Container(new BorderLayout());
    con.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, getMessageContainer(message));
    return con;
}
```

Where `MessageDialog` extends `Dialog`.

This does work well, and I get the following results:

[image: Border with grow short]

And:

[image: Border with grow long]

However, when I remove the border from the theme in the theme.res, turning it into an `Empty` border, I get this as a result:

[image: No grow No Border]

As well as

[image: Grow no border]

This does mean there are some inconsistencies when I wish to remove the border.
Is there any way to get the text to always display when I do not want a border? I tried changing the padding and margin properties, but to no avail.

This is all using the Native theme.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try adding some margin at the bottom of the TextArea. How are you showing your dialog? Are you using `showPacked()` or normal `show()` method?

Answer (score 1):

```
private Container getMessageContainer(String message) {
    Container con = new Container(new BorderLayout());
    TextArea ta = new TextArea();
    ta.setGrowByContent(true);
    ta.setSingleLineTextArea(false);
    ta.setScrollVisible(true);
    ta.setUIID("DialogTextArea");
    ta.setEditable(false);
    ta.setFocusable(false);
    ta.setText(message);

    con.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, ta);
    Label transparentLabel = new Label("");
    transparentLabel.getAllStyle().setBgColor(0xffffffff);
    con.addComponent(BorderLayout.SOUTH, transparentLabel);
    return con;
}
```

This gives a temporary solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the border from the selected, unselected states as well as the padding from both. If you don't do that we will pick the "most" option and go with that to prevent "jumping" on every focus change.

Note that selected state is still applicable even if you selected the component to not have focus or editability.